# Why .jsp page is not displaying on a browser?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I had created a simple web application project in eclipse. It includes-

1. A jsp page
2. A servlet and
3. A html file.

jsp page simply includes a text to print like

## Hello

After deploying this project on Google app engine, the only html page is get display. for jsp page it shows 500 server error.
Why this is so ?
web.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Checkgoogleapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.app.checkgoogleapp.CheckgoogleappServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Checkgoogleapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/checkgoogleapp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param> 
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`
```

**This is error log**

```
W 2014-03-28 01:45:54.477

EXCEPTION 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-16aacb2b4ef7a208(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

E 2014-03-28 01:45:54.478

javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

W 2014-03-28 01:45:54.479

Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@9c019f{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~app-anuja/1.374734901225985743}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

C 2014-03-28 01:45:54.481

Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:228)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: What does the GAE log say?

Comment: Well 500 is a server error so you should check the server's logs to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Hi Joachim EXCEPTION java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process- javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable javax.servlet.UnavailableException at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79) at org.
W  com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@9c019f{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~app-anuja/1.3747349012259857
C 2014-03-28 01:45:54.481 Uncaught exception from servlet javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed. at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMa

Comment: hi Thomas, these above mentioned exceptions are showned in server log.

Comment: Please help me. I am trying to solve this problem from last 1 month.

Comment: can you add content of your web.xml

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Checkgoogleapp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.app.checkgoogleapp.CheckgoogleappServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Checkgoogleapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/checkgoogleapp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param> 
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: The server log snippet is too short.

Comment: Hello, I hd done lots of google on this issue bt i didn't get any solution. Will u plz help m to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Add below code in web.xml and try

```
 <context-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bt still the same issue is there.

Comment: -1 No explanation why he should do this and what the "code" does. Just "try"

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Checkgoogleapp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.app.checkgoogleapp.CheckgoogleappServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Checkgoogleapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/checkgoogleapp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
 <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param> 
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: In my application if i used to add simple servlet then it works nicely but when we add jsp with servlet then it shows 500 in web browser.